# In Perl, how can I capture a string of digits from a string containing carriage returns and line feeds?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract the text (characters and numbers) from a multiline string.  Everything I have tried does not strip out the line feeds/carriage returns.

Here is the string in question:

```
"\r\n        50145395\r\n    "
```

In HEX it is: 0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 35 30 31 34 35 33 39 35 0D 0A 20 20 20 20

I have tried the following:

```
$sitename =~ m/(\d+)/g;  
$sitename = $1;
```

and

```
$sitename =~ s/^\D+//g;  
$sitename =~ s/\D+$//g;
```

and

```
$sitename =~ s/^\s+//g;  
$sitename =~ s/\s+$//g;
```

In all cases I cannot get rid of any of the unwanted characters.  I have run this in cygwin perl and Strawberry perl.

Thanks.

Comment: Also see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Comment: Your goal is not clear, so you are getting answers all over the map. Are you trying to grab only the digits? Are you trying to remove the newlines and carriage returns? Are you trying to remove all whitespace?

Comment: This question would be much clearer if you said, "For this example string I want to extract `50145395`.  In all cases the data I want to extract is a string of digits."  4 things make a good question: A clear statement of the problem, some sample code, sample input and matching sample output.  Make sure your sample data includes any edge cases (perhaps a newline is allowed between blocks of digits--in this case `\r\n      50145\r\n395   \rn   ` would be a good sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need, but here is code extracting all words from string

```
my @words = ( $sitename =~ m/(\w+)/g );
```

It can be also done with `split`. But you need to use spaces now:

```
my @words = split( m/\s+/, $sitename );
```

Comment: Just to explain (as far as I understand it): this matches `m` all continuous word parts `\w+` and stores them into an array.  You can combine them into a single string with `join('',@words)`

Answer (score 5):

Capturing match in list context returns captured strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $s = join('', map chr(hex), qw(
    0D 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 35 30 
    31 34 35 33 39 35 0D 0A 20 20 20 20
));

my ($x) = $s =~ /([A-Za-z0-9]+)/;

print "'$x'\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> uio
'50145395'
```

Comment: I am getting the string from an XML document and I put up the hex representation to show the hex characters of this string.

Comment: @Mel: **So?** I used the hex representation of the string to test my code with the exact data you claimed to be using. Anyway, is this part of an attempt to use regular expressions to parse XML?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious one I didn't see in your post:

```
$sitename =~ s/\D//g;
```

This removes all non-digits.  To remove anything but word characters, you could:

```
$sitename =~ s/\W//g;
```

There's no need for `^` or `$` if your intention is to replace every non-digit.  Also, you can replace one character at a time if you use the global `g` option; no need to match more than one digit with `\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: My solution was incorrect; please instead pay attention to Sinan Ünür's solution.

Comment: But the `s` has no effect if you're not using `.` ? hehe

Comment: There is no **`.`** character in the pattern so this is completely and utterly irrelevant.

Comment: The point is, the expression is applied to the entire string, instead of a line at a time.

Comment: @Conrad Meyer: `m//` and `s///` is always applied to the entire string. The `s` modifier changes how the **pattern** is interpreted.

Comment: Aha! Please forgive my lack of Perl knowledge. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have done something like:

```
my $newline = chr(13) . chr(10);

$data =~ s/$newline/ /g;
```

You can check out other ascii character codes at: http://www.asciitable.com./

```
use strict;

my $newline = chr(13);
my $newline2 = chr(10);

my $words = "\r\n        50145395\r\n    ";

foreach my $char (split //, $words) {
 my $val=ord($char);    
 print "->$char<- ($val)\n";
}

print "$words\n";

$words =~ s/$newline//g;
$words =~ s/$newline2//g;
$words =~ s/[ ]+//g;

foreach my $char (split //, $words) {
 my $val=ord($char);    
 print "->$char<- ($val)\n";
}

print "$words\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove only newlines and carriage returns? If so, this is what you want:

```
$sitename =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
```

If you want to remove all whitespace, not just newlines and linefeeds, use this instead:

```
$sitename =~ s/\s//g;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = <<END;
this is a multiline 
string. this is a multiline
string.
END

$x =~ s/\r?\n?//g;
print $x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all digits, strip off non-digit characters

> $sitename ="\r\n        50145395\r\n    ";
>
> $sitename =~ s/\D+//g;